# How to put an Elemental field under a tab in admin CMS form

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Starting out with the [Elemental module](https://github.com/dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental) for Silverstripe 4 and by default it lists the Elemental area(s) under the Main "Content" tab. I'd like to put them under their own tab.

How do I do that in my Page class getCMSField function?

What I have is:

A specific page (ElementPage) for using the module

```
ElementPage:
  extensions:
    - DNADesign\Elemental\Extensions\ElementalPageExtension
```

In `ElementPage.php` I have two `$has_one` like this:

```
private static $has_one = [
    'LeftElemental' => ElementalArea::class,
    'RightElemental' => ElementalArea::class
];
```

Those work fine, fields display and can render them in the template.

Trying to put them under their own tab, the getCMSFields:

```
public function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    // To remove the default added one
    $fields->removeByName('ElementalArea');

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.LeftContentBlocks', ElementalArea::create('LeftElementalID'));

    return $fields;
}
```

Resulting error:

> [User Warning] DataObject::__construct passed The value
>   'LeftElementalID'. It's supposed to be passed an array, taken straight
>   from the database. Perhaps you should use DataList::create()->First();
>   instead?

I didn't really expect that to work but I can't see the create signature it needs.

**EDIT:**

This seems to get it done:

```
public function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    // To remove the default added one
    $fields->removeByName('ElementalArea');

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.LeftContentBlocks', ElementalAreaField::create('LeftElemental', $this->LeftElemental(), $this->getElementalTypes()));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.RightContentBlocks', ElementalAreaField::create('RightElemental', $this->RightElemental(), $this->getElementalTypes()));

    return $fields;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure `$this->getElementalTypes()` is what I should be doing. Any improvements/corrections are welcomed.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, rather than an edit to your question

Comment: @RobbieAverill I didn't as I wasn't confident it was a solution (see last line). Is how I've done it the right way to do it?